# Android espresso matching intent with bundle inside a bundle

Tags: android-intent, android-espresso, android-testing, hamcrest

I am trying to match value that is inside a bundle of bundle ([see image](https://postimg.org/image/47nap7eth/)).

I need to verify that that **uriString="file:///storage/emulated...."** is set.

But so far with my code, I can verify upto **value[1]="Benefits Card provied by"** only.

```
intended(IntentMatchers.hasExtras(BundleMatchers.hasValue(hasExtras(BundleMatchers.hasValue("test - Prescription Card")))));
```

Comment: Image is not visible anymore

Answer (score 0):

Though this is old and has probably been resolved, I think it's worth noting to try and use `hasExtras` along with nested `hasEntry`.

For a nested bundle like -> `extras: [Bundle[{key=Bundle[<more data>]}]]`
One can try -> `hasExtras(hasEntry(<key>), hasEntry(<key>, <arg>))`